# I am trying to accept an alert but , getting an error like "Unable to accept Alert"

Tags: alert, katalon-studio

I am getting an error when trying to accept an alert. I tried getting the alert text message from the alert. I was able to get the message using WebUI.getAlertText() after adding the below details in Project> WebUI Chrome Settings

[image]

Version Details :
Chrome browserVersion: 107.0.5304.122
chromedriverVersion: 107.0.5304.62

[image]

But still I am unable to accept or decline the alert.

I also tried using WebDriver:

//WebDriver myDriver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()

//myDriver.switchTo().alert().accept();
**
Still facing the error. Please help...

Any other settings to be made?
**
Error Details as below:

```
ERROR c.k.k.core.keyword.internal.KeywordMain  - ❌ Unable to accept alert (Root cause: com.kms.katalon.core.exception.StepFailedException: Unable to accept alert
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.stepFailed(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:64)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:26)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.AcceptAlertKeyword.acceptAlert(AcceptAlertKeyword.groovy:71)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.AcceptAlertKeyword.execute(AcceptAlertKeyword.groovy:66)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.acceptAlert(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:1522)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$acceptAlert$14.call(Unknown Source)
    at TC-RXF-T186-Administration-Benefit-Config-Create-Plan.run(TC-RXF-T186-Administration-Benefit-Config-Create-Plan:145)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:448)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:439)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:418)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:410)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:285)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:142)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:133)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1669612699119.run(TempTestCase1669612699119.groovy:25)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.122)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'CLVITN-GN78GG3', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_282'
Driver info: com.kms.katalon.selenium.driver.CChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 107.0.5304.122, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 107.0.5304.62 (1eec40d3a576..., userDataDir: C:\Users\U6070629\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50294}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 0eb4ccf902aabae64bfb75971a179026
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at com.kms.katalon.selenium.driver.CChromeDriver.execute(CChromeDriver.java:19)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:609)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteAlert.accept(RemoteWebDriver.java:947)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringAlert.accept(EventFiringWebDriver.java:795)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.AcceptAlertKeyword$_acceptAlert_closure1.doCall(AcceptAlertKeyword.groovy:75)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.AcceptAlertKeyword$_acceptAlert_closure1.call(AcceptAlertKeyword.groovy)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.internal.WebUIKeywordMain.runKeyword(WebUIKeywordMain.groovy:20)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.AcceptAlertKeyword.acceptAlert(AcceptAlertKeyword.groovy:71)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.builtin.AcceptAlertKeyword.execute(AcceptAlertKeyword.groovy:66)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.keyword.internal.KeywordExecutor.executeKeywordForPlatform(KeywordExecutor.groovy:74)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords.acceptAlert(WebUiBuiltInKeywords.groovy:1522)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords$acceptAlert$14.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script1564390069306.run(Script1564390069306.groovy:145)
    ... 11 more
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some [waiting time](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/legacy/katalon-studio-enterprise/keywords/web-ui-keywords/webui-wait-for-alert) for the alert to be present:

```
WebUI.waitForAlert(20)
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I am able to get the text(message) of the alert. Tried adding waitforalert. Still fails.

Comment: Any help here....

Comment: Does it fail with the same message?